# Failed to load resource at admin screen

Tags: uploads, wp-admin, media-library

So I've done Wordpress clean install in a live server. Everything looks fine and seems to work. However, if I go to the admin's edit page or post and try to add or change the featured image, the Media Library popup wont appear (it would go to a separate page and upload the image (still, this is buggy).

I checked the console and I get the following errors:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
>   http://motifpatterns.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=88&action=edit&message=6
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
>   http://motifpatterns.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=88&action=edit&message=6#screen-options-wrap

I've tried switching to the default theme and I still get these errors. Are these errors related to some kind of server incompatibility? It's really annoying.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: BTW, no plugins are installed (clean install)

Comment: Please see this answer. This is probably the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24458653/1361532

Comment: Could be, sucks that the errors are kind of generic... I might not be able to solve this.